# Button Hidden and clickable when press "enter" in not a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using ajax to submit a form without refreshing the page.

The problem is, I want to submit the form by pressing enter. If I was using a form field it would be easy, cause I only had to put,

```
hidden="true"
```

here is my code:

```
<div id="form">
 <input type="text" id="text" />
 <button hidden="true" id="submit_button"></button>
</div>
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       document.getElementById("submit_button").onclick= function(){submit_form()}

       /*
       ajax request to submit.php
       */;
});
```

Comment: why mixing javascript and jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to keyDown event.

```
$('#text').keydown(function (e){ //OR on keyup
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        submit_form()
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you :D Worked just fine, don't even remember the keydown event :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
 var key = e.which;
 if(key == 13)  // the enter key code
  {
    submit_form()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand, but if you want to can add the keypress trigger into the inbox:

```
$('#text').keydown(function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 13){
      // Do as you need, ex:
      $('#form').submit();
      return false;
   }
   else return true;
});
```